# Fulton algebraic curves 2.53, is his method overcomplicated?

Tags: linear-algebra

I am looking at Fulton's algebraic curves problem 2.53

[image]

The cited problem 2.49(c) is just the isomorphism theorems for vector spaces. My confusion is that it seems to me that one can conclude (d) with much less work than is implied by the steps Fulton lays out. I want to say: suppose I have subspaces, $V \supset W \supset W'$ and $V \supset V' \supset W'$ with $\dim{V/W} = \dim{V'/W'}$ then $\dim{V/V'} = \dim{W/W'}$ which follows immediately from the second isomorphism theorem:
$$ V / W \cong (V / W')/(W / W') \quad \text{ and } \quad  V / V' \cong (V / W') / (V' / W') $$
and therefore,
$$ \dim(V/W) = \dim(V/W') - \dim(W/W') = \dim(V/V') + \dim(V'/W') - \dim{(W/W')} = \dim{(V'/W')} $$
Then I apply this to the situation at hand with $V' = T(V)$ and $W' = T(W)$.

Did I make a mistake? Is there some reason Fulton doesn't suggest this seemingly easier argument?

Comment: Does he assume everything is finite dimensional?

Comment: @Randall no but the assumption is that V/W and W/W′ are finite-dimensional meaning that V/W′ and hence all the quotients above are indeed finite-dimensional.